# Thermodynamics Potentials Relations

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential, functional-derivatives

I tried to find the whole connections between the thermodynamics potentials without any success,
the main potentials $U,F,G,H$ and the relations between them (derivatives), for an example what is the derivative of $dU/dT$ while $G$ and $N$ are constants.
if someone can send me to a place where i can find all of these connections it will be great.
Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Try here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/thepot.html#c1

Answer (score 1):

[Prof. Rebecca Brannon's scheme](https://csm.mech.utah.edu/ThermoDerivativeRecursionTables.pdf) is an excellent resource for looking up or evaluating complex thermostatic derivatives such as $(\partial U/\partial T)_{G,N}$, which turns out to be $\alpha_P T(VB_S-S)-P(VB_V-S)/K_T$, where $\alpha_P$ is the thermal expansion coefficient at constant pressure, $B_X$ is the change in pressure with respect to temperature at constant $X$ (here, entropy or volume), and $K_T$ is the isothermal bulk modulus. (All parameters are taken at constant $N$.)

Table 5-1 [here](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25018/6/TOE05.pdf) gives the equivalent $(\partial U/\partial T)_G=mc_P-\alpha TS-P\alpha V-PS/K_T$ and is easier to use but gives less explanation and insight.

Comment: Hi, first thank you very much for your answer, you are the first one in many sites who could provide any answer. I entered the link you shared in your comment but could not find there the solution to this derivative, more important is to find a place that organize all the thermodynamics relations of these complex derivatives, i couldn't find it in any book or site... do you know where can i find all of these relations?

Comment: The process is to code $(\partial U/\partial T)_G$ as UTG, which is found on p10 to correspond to T STG - P VTG, which in turn can be looked up, and so on. The table on p11 translates certain combinations into material properties. There might be some software that does this automatically, but I don't know of any.